# Selecting and combining 2 rows from multiple tables using Left()

Tags: sql

This function that I have does what I want, but just wondering if there is a way to do it in one go:

```
drop table ##aa
select s.storeid,cast(LEFT(p.paytype,1) as varchar(50)) as Paytype,SUM(amount) as Total
into ##aa
from RPTrs s, rpPay p
where s.storeid=p.StoreID and s.ReceiptNO=p.ReceiptNo 
and trsdate between '1/1/06' and '1/1/13'
group by s.storeid,LEFT(p.paytype,1)

update A set a.paytype=b.currencydesc
from ##aa a, Currencies b
where a.Paytype=b.POSCurrency

select * from ##aa order by Paytype, StoreID
```

What I am asking is, I want to apply the b.CurrencyDesc to the initial p.paytype. The Paytype just displays C as example but I want it to stand for Cash, and V for Visa and such as it is described in the Currencies table

Comment: Please don't use `BETWEEN` for date/time types, [especially if you happen to be on SQL Server](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) (The article explains why this is particularly perilous for SQL Server, but other RDBMSs have related concerns).  Frankly, I personally find it's the wrong way to _think_ about date/time values; it's better to think of them as an 'imprecise' ranged value, similar to how (decimal) floating point is dealt with.  So your ending is anytime before `1/2/13`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you can add a `JOIN`:

```
select   s.storeid
       , b.currencydesc as Paytype
       , SUM(amount)    as Total
into     ##aa
from     RPTrs s

join     rpPay p
on       s.storeid=p.StoreID
     and s.ReceiptNO=p.ReceiptNo

join     Currencies b 
on       b.POSCurrency=cast(LEFT(p.paytype,1) as varchar(50))

where    trsdate between '1/1/06' and '1/1/13'
group by s.storeid
       , b.currencydesc
```

Converted to use explicit join syntax.  Can't tell what table contributes `trsdate`.  And I'm not sure the `CAST` is needed on the join condition.

Comment: I'm not sure you need the `into ##aa` at this point, as the OP's last line is just selecting from the (presumed temp) table.  If so, you're missing the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I kept `into` and omitted the `ORDER BY` because the question was about combining the two steps.  Your suggested changes will likely further help, but I'll leave that to the OP.  Doesn't say what DB; I'm guessing MySQL.

Comment: Thank you so much, that has worked. It is MsSQL that I am using. I did take out the temp table and the cast as they were not needed anymore. The Cast was so the temp table has the space to put in the new information that is longer then 1 character. Appreciate your help guys.

Comment: Please remember to "accept" this answer if it's acceptable; that removes it from the "unanswered" question list (and adds to your reputation).  And welcome to StackOverflow!